# How to display Dropdown selected Item using Angular5/6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I want to display selected item in Dropdown list based on id.

```
<div class="formrow" *ngFor='let a of applicantName'>
  <label>Status Selection :</label>
  <select id="AStatus" formControlName="AStatus" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option *ngFor="let apt of applicantStatus" [value]="apt.ApplicantStatusID" [selected]="apt.ApplicantStatusID === a.Status">
      {{ apt.ApplicantStatus }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This code is not working and not showing selected option.

Comment: I'd bind the dropdown value to a `ngModel` and this model can be set with the value of `id`

Comment: well, you can use the ngModel and then it will simply set the selected on the value.

Comment: You can make use of data-binding on the selected option model.

Comment: Show us your `ts`, how is AStatus defined? Did you try [formControlName]=....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` should be set for select not for option.

```
<div class="formrow" *ngFor='let a of applicantName'>
  <label>Status Selection :</label>
  <select id="AStatus" [value]="apt.ApplicantStatusID" formControlName="AStatus" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option *ngFor="let apt of applicantStatus" [value]="apt.ApplicantStatusID">
      {{ apt.ApplicantStatus }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The value must also be set on the options. Otherwise, the `select` element cannot match its value with the corresponding option.

Comment: That make sense. so you can add in both places and check

Comment: Updated the answer.